# Binary search not giving the correct output

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

I am trying to sort an array using Binary Search, but I don't know why I am not getting the correct outputs.

My code is-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int BinarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x){
    int mid = l + (r-l)/2;
   if(l<=r){ 
    if(arr[mid] == x ){
        return mid;

    }
    else if (arr[mid] > x){
        BinarySearch(arr , l, mid-1, x);
    }
    else {
        BinarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
    }


   

    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
    int x = 3;
    int len = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);


    int p = BinarySearch(arr, 0, len -1, x);
    (p==-1) ? cout<<"The element is not present in the array"
            : cout<<"The element is present in the array at index " << p;
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving the output as "The element is not found in the array".
I tried for some other value of x such as 7,9 but it gives the same wrong output.
Can somebody tell me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: If you declare a function to return a value, you must explicitly have a `return` statement. And without an explicit `return` statement the function will continue to its end. With that in mind, what do you return when you call `BinarySearch` recursively?

Comment: @Some programmer dude  I have returned mid if it finds the number in the array and -1 if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes you return `mid` if the element is found. But what do you return when you call `BinarySearch(arr , l, mid-1, x)`? You unconditionally return `-1` even if the recursive function found the element! You should do `return BinarySearch(arr , l, mid-1, x);` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I have used the same code as given here- <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/>  

I think -1 is returned only when the input is not found. Can you please elaborate your point?

Comment: No you have *not* used the code from that link, since the C++ examples used **`return`** for returning the result of the recursive calls! Doing a recursive call does *not* automatically return anything. To return a value you *must* have an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  ohh, I just saw the problem with my code. Thanks for your time. Have a nice day!